# Download multiple files in streamlit

Tags: python, pandas, csv, streamlit

I am writing a program to concate and modify some CSV files. My code returns 5 or fewer DataFrames to me. I want to allow users to download all these DataFrames as CSV files, but `st.download_button` allows me to download only one. I Try to make just a few buttons but when I click the first rest just disappears.
This is my code :

```py
uploaded_files = st.file_uploader("Proszę wybrać pliki csv", accept_multiple_files=True)
if st.button("Rozpocznij proces"):
        data1 = structure.create_structure(uploaded_files)
        @st.cache
        def convert_df(df):
            # IMPORTANT: Cache the conversion to prevent computation on every rerun
            return df.to_csv().encode('utf-8')
        mlode = convert_df(data1[0])
        lochy = convert_df(data1[1])
        knury = convert_df(data1[2])
        rozplodowa = convert_df(data1[3])
        mag = convert_df(data1[4])
        #choices = st.multiselect("Download",["mlode","lochy","knury","rozplodowa"])
        razem = ['mlode','lochy','knury','rozplodowa','mag']

        st.download_button(label="Download mlode as CSV",
                          data = mlode,
                           file_name="mlode.csv")

        st.download_button(label="Download lochy as CSV",
                           data=lochy,
                           file_name="lochy.csv")

        st.download_button(label="Download lochy as CSV",
                           data=knury,
                           file_name="knury.csv")

        st.download_button(label="Download lochy as CSV",
                           data=rozplodowa,
                           file_name="rozplodowa.csv")

        st.download_button(label="Download lochy as CSV",
                           data=mag,
                           file_name="mag.csv")
```

Is there any way to download multiple files using `st.download_button` ?

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** the `download button`, the **problem is from** `if st.button("Rozpocznij proces"):`

Streamlit button has no **callbacks** so any user **entry** under a `st.button()` will always rerun the app so you end up losing the data, in that case you will have to `initialize` a `session state` for `st.button()` or you can **replace** `if st.button("Rozpocznij proces"):` with a **checkbox** like `if st.checkbox("Rozpocznij proces"):` and you will be fine to go.

Change

```py
if st.button("Rozpocznij proces"):
```

To

```py
if st.checkbox("Rozpocznij proces"):
```

I also recommend you create a function as well for your download button which will make your work much better instead of repeating almost same code over and over again.

But before we do that lets first rename these variables so we can have a clear understanding when entering the function arguments.

```py
mlode_csv = convert_df(data1[0]) # I added csv to the variable names
lochy_csv = convert_df(data1[1])
knury_csv = convert_df(data1[2])
rozplodowa_csv = convert_df(data1[3])
mag_csv = convert_df(data1[4])
```

Now lets construct our `download_button` function.

```py
import streamlit as st
import csv
def generate_download_button(csv_data, filename, file_label):
    st.download_button(label=f"Download {file_label} as CSV",
                           data=csv_data,
                           file_name=f"{filename}.csv")


generate_download_button(csv_data=mlode_csv, filename="mlode", file_label="mlode")

generate_download_button(csv_data=lochy_csv, filename="lochy", file_label="lochy")

generate_download_button(csv_data=knury_csv, filename="knury", file_label="knury")

generate_download_button(csv_data=rozplodowa_csv, filename="rozplodowa", file_label="rozplodowa")

generate_download_button(csv_data=mag_csv, filename="mag", file_label="mag")
```

Whenever you call `generate_download_button`it will generate a new download button.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with one download button afaik. A workaround would be to zip the selected files and use the zip file for the download.

Answer (score 0):

Since [`st.download_button`](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/widgets/st.download_button) doesn't allow (yet) to download multiple files, you can try to zip all your dataframes/csvs so can the users download them at once.

You may need to take a look at this [article](https://blog.devgenius.io/export-zip-of-multiple-csv-files-in-django-50d853143db3) that explains how to do that in [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) and I think it's much more simpler to do it in [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/).